# Django Rest Framework Forbidden when i send post request

Tags: reactjs, django, django-rest-framework, axios

I am making a website with django rest framework backend and a react frontend but when i use axios to send a post request to /products it sends a 403 forbidden error

this is the views file

```
@api_view(['GET', 'POST'])
def products(request):
    if request.method == 'GET':
        products = Product.objects.all()
        serializer = ProductSerializer(products, many=True)
        return Response(serializer.data)
        
elif request.method == 'POST':
    serializer = ProductSerializer(data=request.data)
    print(request.data)
    if serializer.is_valid():
        serializer.save()
        return Response(serializer.data, status=status.HTTP_201_CREATED)
    return Response(serializer.errors, status=status.HTTP_400_BAD_REQUEST)
```

this is how i send the request in react:

```
const handleSave = () => (
    axios.post('/products', getInputData()).then((response) => (console.log(response)))
);
```

this is my settings file in django:

```
ALLOWED_HOSTS = []


# Application definition

INSTALLED_APPS = [
    'django.contrib.admin',
    'django.contrib.auth',
    'django.contrib.contenttypes',
    'django.contrib.sessions',
    'django.contrib.messages',
    'django.contrib.staticfiles',
    'corsheaders',
    'rest_framework',
    'API',
]

MIDDLEWARE = [
    'django.middleware.security.SecurityMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.sessions.middleware.SessionMiddleware',
    'corsheaders.middleware.CorsMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.common.CommonMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.csrf.CsrfViewMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.auth.middleware.AuthenticationMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.messages.middleware.MessageMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.clickjacking.XFrameOptionsMiddleware',
]

CORS_ORIGIN_ALLOW_ALL = False

CORS_ORIGIN_WHITELIST = (
    'http://localhost:3000',
)
```

Comment: Are you sending the CSRF token with your request?

Comment: how do i do that?

Comment: Include the CSRF token in the headers. Might also depend on all your settings. See [Cross Site Request Forgery protection](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.2/ref/csrf/#ajax).

Answer (score 1):

so here is what I ended up doing

```
function getCookie(name) {
    let cookieValue = null;
    if (document.cookie && document.cookie !== '') {
        const cookies = document.cookie.split(';');
        for (let i = 0; i < cookies.length; i++) {
            const cookie = cookies[i].trim();
            // Does this cookie string begin with the name we want?
            if (cookie.substring(0, name.length + 1) === (name + '=')) {
                cookieValue = decodeURIComponent(cookie.substring(name.length + 1));
                break;
            }
        }
    }
    return cookieValue;
}

function add_product(data) {
    const csrftoken = getCookie('csrftoken');

    const config = {
        headers: {
            'content-type': 'application/json',
            'X-CSRFToken': csrftoken,
        }
    }

    axios.post('/products', data, config).then((response) => (alert(response))

}
```